# How to store string data in a collection and then list all in collection?

Tags: android, collections

I am creating an organiser app and am looking to get the string and date data entered by the user and then save it. Then be able to list all of the events on another page. the current inputs use EditText and are name, description, date and location. How would I go about doing this? i am a total novice at android and am also using eclipse to develop.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values from the editText into separate strings. once you have taken these values in strings you can store them in a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) using the putExtras or putString method.

and then create an Intent to go to the other activity and add this Bundle to that intent by using `Intent.putExtras(Bundle)`.

In the oncreate of the other activity you can extract data from the bundle using
    `Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras();`

and retrieve each element of the Bundle into separate strings and display them.

and if you plan to have persistent storage you should thing of using `SQLite database` for storing data by using `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how long you wanted to keep this information. I'm going to assume since you're in the process of designing an Organizer Application that you'll want to have access to this data after your application has been killed and re-opened.

In my opinion storing these information in a database (most likely [using SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)) would be the most logical way to go about this since it'll be way easier to query this information if you do decide you want to implement some kind of sorting algorithm in the future.

Another option, you could also use the [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

You might want to take a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) as it explains various ways of storing persisting information on Android.